# Insert image in caption

Tags: graphics

I manage to use graphical images in both text and tables as if they were letters:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\inspictext}{  \includegraphics[width=0.04\textwidth]{example-image-b}}

\begin{document}

Some text \inspictext
\begin{table}
  \newcommand{\inspic}{  \includegraphics[width=0.04\textwidth]{example-image-a}}
  \begin{tabular}{llc}
    A &\inspic \\
    B &\inspic \\
  \end{tabular}
  %  \caption{the symbol \inspictext is ..}                                                                                                                                                                
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This is confirmed in the output:

[image]

I would like to use an image also in the table caption. Therefore, I uncomment the line

```
   %  \caption{the symbol \inspictext is ..}
```

I get an error:

```
! Argument of \@caption has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.14     \caption{the symbol \inspictext is ..}
```

How to fix?

Comment: `\protect\inspictext`

Comment: Use `\protect\inspictext` in the argument of `\caption`, or define `\inspictext` by means of `\DeclareRobustCommand` instead of `\newcommand`.